# Should a single command address multiple aggregates?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

In CQRS and DDD, an aggregate is a transactional boundary. Hence I have been modeling commands always in such a way that each command always only ever addresses a single aggregate. Of course, technically, it would be possible to write a command handler that addresses multiple aggregates, but that would not be within a single transaction and hence would not be consistent.

If you actually have to address multiple aggregates, I usually go with a process manager, but this sometimes feels like pretty much overhead. In addition, from my understanding a process manager always only reacts to domain events, it is not directly addressed by commands. So you need to decide which aggregate to put the starting point to.

I have seen that some people solve this using so-called domain or application services, which can receive commands as well, and then work on multiple aggregates – but in this case the transactional nature of the process gets lost.

To give a simple example, to better illustrate the scenario:

- A user shall join a group.
- A user has a max number of groups.
- A group has a max number of users.

Where to put the command that triggers the initial joining process, and what to call it? `user.join(group)` feels as right or wrong as `group.welcome(user)`. I'd probably go for the first one, because this is closer to the ubiquitous language, but anyway…

If I had something above the aggregates, like the aforementioned services, then I could run something such as:

```
userManagement.addUserToGroup(user, group);
```

However, this `addUserToGroup` function would then need to call both commands, which in turn means it has to take care of both commands being processed – which is somewhat counterintuitive to having separate aggregates at all, and having aggregates as transactional boundaries.

What would be the correct way to model this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially what you have is many to many relationships between users and groups with restrictions on both sides:

- Restriction on the number of groups a user can join
- Restriction on the number of users a group can have

VoiceOfUnreason already gave a great answer, so I'll share one way I've solved similar problems and go straight to the model and implementation in case you have to ensure that these constraints are enforced at all costs. If you don't have to, do not make the model and implementation that complex.

Ensuring consistency with such constraints on both **Group** and **User** entities will be difficult in a single operation because of the concurrency of the operations.

You can model this by adding a collection of **RegisteredUsers** to a **Group** or vice versa, adding a collection of **JoinedGroups** to a **User**, and enforce the constraint on one side, but enforcing it on the other side is still an issue.

What you can do is introduce another concept in your domain. The concept of a 
"Slot" in a **Group**. "Slots" are limited by the max number of **Slots** for a **Group**.

Then a **User** will issue a **JoinGroupRequest** that can be **Accepted** or **Rejected**.

A **Slot** can be either **Taken** or **Reserved**. Then you can introduce the concept of **SlotReservation**. The process of joining a **User** to a **Group** will be:

- Issue a **JoinGroupRequest** from a **User**
- Try to **Reserve** a **Slot** enforcing the **MaxUsersPerGroup** constraint.
- **Acquire** a **Slot** or **Reject** the **SlotReservation** of a **User** enforcing the **MaxGroupsPerUser** constraint.
- **Accept** or **Reject** the **JoinGroupRequest** depending on the outcome of the **SlotReservation**

If the **SlotReservation** is **Rejected**, another **User** will be able to use this **Slot** later.

For the implementation, you can add **SlotReservation Queue Per Group** to ensure that once a **Slot** is free after a **Rejected SlotReservation**, the next **User** that wants to join the **Group** will be able to.

For the implementation, you can add a collection of **Slots** to a **Group**, or you can make **Slot** an aggregate in its own right.

You can use a Saga for this process. The Saga will be triggered when a **JoinGroupRequest** is made by a **User**.

Essentially, this operation becomes a [Tentative Operation](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/conversation/TryConfirmCancel.html).

For more details take a look and the [Accountability Pattern](https://martinfowler.com/apsupp/accountability.pdf) and [Life beyond distributed transactions an apostate's opinion](https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=3025012) and [Life beyond distributed transactions an apostate's implementation](https://jimmybogard.com/life-beyond-transactions-implementation-primer/).

Comment: How do you enforce the **MaxGroupsPerUser** constraint while handling concurrency issues? Do you store the number of groups the user is in somewhere?

Comment: The user makes **JoinGroupRequests**. A request has three statuses:  **Pending**, **Accepted** or **Rejected**. You need to record the requests a user makes, so you can enforce the **MaxGroupsPerUser**. The number of **Pending** and **Accepted** requests should not exceed **MaxGroupsPerUser**. You may also need to remove **Users** from **Groups**. This will depend on the domain and the rules there. For example you can remove a **JoinGroupRequests** when the **User** leaves (or is removed/banned from) a **Group** or have more statuses of the **JoinGroupRequest**: **LeftGroup**, **Banned**, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It may be worth reviewing Greg Young on [Eventual Consistency and Set Validation](https://web.archive.org/web/20190109214934/http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/08/12/eventual-consistency-and-set-validation/).

> *What is the business impact of having a failure*
>
> This is the key question we need to ask and it will drive our solution
> in how to handle this issue as we have many choices of varying degrees
> of difficulty.

And certainly Pat Helland on [Memories, Guesses, and Apologies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/pathelland/memories-guesses-and-apologies).

Short version: the two generals tell us that, if two pieces of information must be consistent, then we need to write both pieces of information in the same place.  The "invariant" constrains our data model.

The invariant you describe is effectively a couple of set validation problems: the "membership" collection allows only so many members with user A, and only so many members with group B.  And if you really are in a "we go out of business if those rules are violated" situation, then you *cannot* distribute the members of that set -- you have to lock the entire set when you modify it to ensure that the rule is not broken and that first writer wins.

An element that requires some care in your modeling: is the domain model the authority for membership? or is the "real world" responsible for membership and the domain model is just caching that information for later use?  You want to be very careful about trying to enforce an invariant on the real world.

There's a risk that you end up over constraining the order in which information is accepted by the model.